# Extracting exact distance information for an animation

Tags: rendering, camera, units

so basically what I want to do is have the exact distance between my Camera and an object, preferably in the metric system, for every frame of my animation.
I have been looking into the camera properties but can not seem to find anything for that, i have managed to change the units to metric but that's about it.

Comment: does the object you want the camera to stay relative to move?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **"MeasureIt"** add-on: enable it from the user preferences.

Then select your two objects and, from the left panel of the 3D viewport (<kbd>T</kbd>), look for "MeasureIt" and click on "Link" under the "Add measure" box. Then hit "Show" to visualize it, if it isn't displayed already.

[image: MeasureIt]